# Collect result of few Futures (i.e. join) at once

Tags: java, asynchronous

I have a thread pool that creates futures for various tasks. Sometimes, I need to join e.g. 3 such futures at one place. For example:

```
Future f1 = asyncRun("one");
Future f2 = asyncRun("two");
Future f3 = asyncRun("three");
```

Later in the code I have a point where I must have all 3 results. I was thinking to make a util method and the best I can think of is:

```
public static <V> V[] get(Class<V> type, Future<V>... futures) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    V[] values = (V[]) Array.newInstance(type, futures.length);

    for (int i = 0; i < futures.length; i++) {
        Future<V> future = futures[i];
        values[i] = future.get();
    }
    return values;
}
```

which is ugly, as I need to provide class name for the future value.

Any better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you have to pass `Class<V>` doesn't really have anything to do with concurrency or futures, it's just because you want to return an array of a generic type. Arrays and generics unfortunately don't work very well together in Java.

You could return a `List<V>` instead of an array:

```
public static <V> List<V> get(Future<V>... futures) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    List<V> values = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < futures.length; i++){
        values.add(futures[i].get());
    }

    return values;
}
```

If you absolutely want an array, then you can convert it the usual way at the point you call this:

```
Future<String> f1 = asyncRun("one");
Future<String> f2 = asyncRun("two");
Future<String> f3 = asyncRun("three");

String[] result = get(f1, f2, f3).toArray(new String[3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Return a List instead of array?

Or else, you could grab the class reference from the first of the objects you get: 
`Class<V> type = futures[0].get().getClass()`

Comment: Like the first suggestion, but the second one is problematic. `futures[0].get().getClass()` could be a subclass of `V`, and `futures[1].get().getClass()` could be a different subclass of `V`, or `V` itself; so that only really works if `V` refers to a `final` class.

Comment: Not really, this is not scala, there is no covariance in generics. `Future<V>.get()` has to return V, not a subclass of V.
That is, if everything is done "by the book". But I agree with you, that it is unreliable, as one can "coerce" Future<V> to contain, a subclass (or, in fact, anything at all).

Comment: A `Future<Number> x` is allowed to return an `Integer`. You can't assign `Future<Integer> y` to `x`, but you're certainly allowed to return an `Integer` from a method that is declared to return a `Number`